# Ошибка при @OneToMany и @ManyToOne

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Вне зависимости от попыток что-либо изменить вылетает одно и та же ошибка.**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "services")
public class Service {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "service_name")
    private String nameOfService;

    @Column(name = "cost")
    private Integer serviceCost;

    @Column(name = "category")
    private String category;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "type_of_service")
    private String typeOfService;

    @Column(name = "currency")
    private String currency;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getNameOfService() {
        return nameOfService;
    }

    public void setNameOfService(String nameOfService) {
        this.nameOfService = nameOfService;
    }

    public Integer getServiceCost() {
        return serviceCost;
    }

    public void setServiceCost(Integer serviceCost) {
        this.serviceCost = serviceCost;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getTypeOfService() {
        return typeOfService;
    }

    public void setTypeOfService(String typeOfService) {
        this.typeOfService = typeOfService;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

---

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "is_registration_confirmed")
        private Boolean isRegistrationConfirmed;

        @Column(name = "key_for_registration_confirm")
        private String keyForRegistrationConfirmUrl;

        @Column(name = "login")
        private String login;

        @Column(name = "date_of_registration")
        private Date dateOfRegistration;

        @Transient
        private String confirmPassword;

        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "gender")
        private String gender;

        @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
        private String dateOfBirth;

        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;

        @Column(name = "path_to_avatar")
        private String avatar;

        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
        private Set<Role> roles;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", /*cascade = CascadeType.ALL, */fetch = FetchType.LAZY/*, orphanRemoval = true*/)
        private Set<Service> services;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Boolean getRegistrationConfirmed() {
            return isRegistrationConfirmed;
        }

        public void setRegistrationConfirmed(Boolean registrationConfirmed) {
            isRegistrationConfirmed = registrationConfirmed;
        }

        public String getKeyForRegistrationConfirmUrl() {
            return keyForRegistrationConfirmUrl;
        }

        public void setKeyForRegistrationConfirmUrl(String keyForRegistrationConfirmUrl) {
            this.keyForRegistrationConfirmUrl = keyForRegistrationConfirmUrl;
        }

        public String getLogin() {
            return login;
        }

        public void setLogin(String login) {
            this.login = login;
        }

        public Date getDateOfRegistration() {
            return dateOfRegistration;
        }

        public void setDateOfRegistration(Date dateOfRegistration) {
            this.dateOfRegistration = dateOfRegistration;
        }

        public String getConfirmPassword() {
            return confirmPassword;
        }

        public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
            this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getDateOfBirth() {
            return dateOfBirth;
        }

        public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
            this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        }

        public String getCountry() {
            return country;
        }

        public void setCountry(String country) {
            this.country = country;
        }

        public String getAvatar() {
            return avatar;
        }

        public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
            this.avatar = avatar;
        }

        public Set<Role> getRoles() {
            return roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }

        public Set<Service> getServices() {
            return services;
        }

        public void setServices(Set<Service> services) {
            this.services = services;
        }
}
```

---

**Ошибка:**

```
16:22:30.763 [http-nio-8087-exec-7] ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper#146 Unknown column 'service0_.user_id' in 'field list'
```

Comment: `JoinColumn(name = "user_id")` нужно добавить `reference` и указать с какой колонкой нужно сджоинить

Comment: В Вашей таблице сервисов есть колонка user_id? Или на самом деле она называется userId? И если поле одно, то один из маппингов должен быть readonly (insertable и updateable == false) и это должен быть private Long userId

Comment: Если я вместо user_id попробую подключить userid,то он выдает ERROR o.s.w.c.ContextLoader#353 Context initialization failed.  Есть foreign key user_id

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") попробовал так, но ошибка все та же.

Comment: Добавил insertable и updateable == false к private Long userId, проблема решилась, но можно ли как-то связать не с этим полем, а с внешним ключом user_id? Я хочу избавится от поля userId, а на вместо него хочу использовать user_id

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте изменить имя

```java
 @Column(name = "userid")
```

На

```java
 @Column(name = "user_id")
```

В классе Services, а то у вас колонка в таблице "services" называется userId, а не user_id

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать `@OneToMany(**targetEntity** = Service.class...` вместо `@OneToMany(**mappedBy** = "user"...`